# How to parent facial features to body so rigging doesn't mess up?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I've got this little guy here. His two eyeballs are parented to the main body.

[image]

However, when I rotate his body, the eyes don't stay in their sockets.

[image]

How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent eyes to a main bone instead of body. Or create 2 new bones for eyes, if you want to move eyes

Comment: It works! I didn't know how to parent to a specific bone before. Thanks!